# MySQL query that returns amount of contacts per day of week in subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to come up with a query that enables me to select the amount of contacts a employee has had, per day of week.

I came up with the following, but it returns 0,0,0,0,0 for each day and each employee.

```
SELECT
@emp := A.id,
A.first_name,
(
   SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(',', mo, tu, we, th, fr)
   FROM
    (
        SELECT
            COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(B.contact_date) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS mo,
             COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(B.contact_date) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS tu,
             COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(B.contact_date) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS we,
             COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(B.contact_date) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS th,
             COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(B.contact_date) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS fr
        FROM
            `contacts` AS B
           WHERE
              B.user_id = @emp
           AND
              YEAR(B.contact_date) = 2018
           AND
              WEEK(B.contact_date) = 2
    ) q
) AS call_attempts
FROM
    `users` AS A
WHERE
    A.deactivated = 0
AND
    A.type = 1
ORDER BY
    A.first_name
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f682c/7

Comment: try to run the sub query first. I already see you are filtering for `AND WEEK(B.contact_date) = 2` so all other days will have 0. Now also check do you have contact_date on tuesday with that @emp on 2018 ?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry i added the fiddle

Comment: Hooray. 2 out of 3.